# C code bubble sorting sometimes does not give correct output

Tags: c, sorting, struct, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort numbers using the bubble sorting method. However, sometimes the output returns some incorrect answers.

Appreciate someone can help how to fix this issue. the C code and incorrect output as below

```
typedef struct
{
    char pname[2];
    int ptotime;
} data;

int main()
{
    int totalwait = 0;
    data name[] = {{'A', .ptotime = 4},
                   {'B', .ptotime = 6},
                   {'C', .ptotime = 3},
                   {'D', .ptotime = 7},
                   {'E', .ptotime = 2}};

    printf("Process Name\t Process Time \n");

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf("\t%s\t\t\t\t%d\n", name[j].pname, name[j].ptotime);
    }

    //Shortest job first (SJF) scheduling
    printf("\nShortest job first (SJF) scheduling \n");

    int swapped, temp;

    while (1)
    {
        swapped = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            if (name[x].ptotime >= name[x + 1].ptotime)
            {
                temp = name[x].ptotime;
                name[x].ptotime = name[x + 1].ptotime;
                name[x + 1].ptotime = temp;
                swapped = 1;
                char temp2[2];
                strcpy(temp2, name[x].pname);
                strcpy(name[x].pname, name[x + 1].pname);
                stpcpy(name[x + 1].pname, temp2);
            }
        }

        if (swapped == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Process Name\t Process Time \n");

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf("\t%s\t\t\t\t%d\n", name[j].pname, name[j].ptotime);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Process Name     Process Time
        A                               4
        B                               6
        C                               3
        D                               7
        E                               2

Shortest job first (SJF) scheduling
Process Name     Process Time
                                        0
        E                               2
        C                               3
        A                               4
        B                               6
```

**Expected output**

```
Process Name     Process Time
        A                               4
        B                               6
        C                               3
        D                               7
        E                               2

Shortest job first (SJF) scheduling
Process Name     Process Time
        E                               2
        C                               3
        A                               4
        B                               6
        D                               7
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C/C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Your array has 5 elements.  What is supposed to happen when the code accesses the non-existent 6th element?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the real output and the expected output *as text*, not as picture.

Comment: Bubble sort is supposed to be [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts). However, your comparison is `>=`. You should remove the `=` part

Comment: I think you are risking undefined behavior by initializing your `char[2]` with `'A'`. How do you ensure that the second character is null? I would use `"A"` as an initializer instead. Similarly for the other instances of the struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters do not use magic numbers as `5`. Use named constants.

The array name is initialized incorrectly. You are using character literals to initialize the data member `pname` of a character array type without enclosing character literals in braces.

```
data name[] = {{'A', .ptotime = 4},
                ^^^
//...
```

in this loop

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        if (name[x].ptotime >= name[x + 1].ptotime)
                                    ^^^^^
        //...
```

there is an access beyond the array. So the program has undefined behavior.

Use local variables as for example the variable swap in the shortest scope where they are used.

To swap elements of the array name there is no need to swap each data member of each element of the array. You can swap whole objects.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char pname[2];
    int ptotime;
} data;


int main( void ) 
{ 
    data name[] = 
    {
        { "A", .ptotime = 4 },
        { "B", .ptotime = 6 },
        { "C", .ptotime = 3 },
        { "D", .ptotime = 7 },
        { "E", .ptotime = 2 }
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( name ) / sizeof( *name );

    printf("Process Name\t Process Time \n");

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "\t%s\t\t\t\t%d\n", name[i].pname, name[i].ptotime );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    //Shortest job first (SJF) scheduling

    printf("\nShortest job first (SJF) scheduling \n");

    for ( int swapped = 1; swapped; )
    {
        swapped = 0;

        for ( int i = 1; i < N; i++ ) 
        {
            if ( name[i].ptotime < name[i-1].ptotime )
            {
                data tmp = name[i];
                name[i] = name[i-1];
                name[i-1] = tmp;

                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Process Name\t Process Time \n");

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "\t%s\t\t\t\t%d\n", name[i].pname, name[i].ptotime );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Process Name     Process Time 
    A               4
    B               6
    C               3
    D               7
    E               2


Shortest job first (SJF) scheduling 
Process Name     Process Time 
    E               2
    C               3
    A               4
    B               6
    D               7
```

Comment: a complete informative answer, really helps me a lot as I am a student who trying to learn C/C++. really appreciate your time. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
```

into:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
```

When `x=4`, the code compares `name[4]` with `name[5]`, but `name[5]` is out of bounds (the only valid elements are `name[0]` ... `name[4]`).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. this resolves the bug. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem here:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
      if (name[x].ptotime >= name[x + 1].ptotime) {
```

the maximal value `x` can take is 4. But then `name[x + 1]` will access one element beyond the end of your array which has only 5 elements. Accessing an array out of bounds yields in undefined behaviour and all bets are off.

There may be more problems though.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. this resolves the bug. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In your swap cycle, this code snippet:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
```

In the last iteration you  copy the values of `name[4+1]` to `name[4]` witch is to say you copy the values of the 6th element of your 5 element array, this is **access out of bounds** witch is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Use

```
for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
```

This way the last cycle will be copying `name[3+1]` to `name[3]`, 5th element to 4th element, witch is the expected behaviour.

[**Corrected code**](https://onlinegdb.com/H1nJUK-78)